# CURL class that works like simple HTML DOM?

Tags: dom, curl, screen-scraping

So i've been using both CURL and simple_html_dom for a while, for anyone who is not familiar with simple HTML DOM - It allows you to go through elements with ease and without the hassle of having to use regex/exploding stuff and so on.

E.g.

```
$html = file_get_html($obj->loc);
$item['title'] = $html->find('#Prod-Name h1',0)->plaintext;
```

However as far as i'm aware this does not support cookies - like CURL does, is there something out there that does?

Would be interested to hear peoples experience in this screen scraping/bot creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just download with curl and parse it with the parsing lib of your choice. I use this method sometimes but I'm not very happy with it, it would be nice if php had some decent scraping libs and even nicer if they were built in.

Comment: Somehow overlooked that! Thanks!